# Oracle Scheduler Job not running as per the scheduled time

Tags: oracle, scheduler, jobs

I have a oracle scheduler job created in Oracle 11g XE. I have scheduled the job to run every day 3 times as per local time zone (IST). This job is scheduled to run a stored procedure which performs insert operation on one of the table.

This got ran successfully as per the scheduled time on the day I have created the job but it is not getting run from the next day onwards. Point to note is I have the database setup in my local machine (laptop). After successful execution of the on the 1st day I turned off my machine.

Is this is the reason why my job is not running? Do I need to start some Oracle services every day so that my job runs successfully or is there any parameters that I have set wrongly? I am attaching the screenshot of the job.

Job Details Section1:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle must be running for the Oracle scheduler to work.  To configure Oracle Express Edition to start automatically, go to the Services program and set OracleServiceXE to Automatic.

There is probably also a service called OracleJobSchedulerXE but that service is *not* necessary for regular scheduler jobs.